# My slick slider carousel has an extra white slide. Is there any way to get rid of it?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

So basically Im using a slick slider and its working fine, however after it gets done sliding through all my images it slides to a blank white background and then resets the slider.  Is there any way I can get the slider to reset back to the first slide after it finishes?

Here is the html that I am using:

```
<section id="home-slider">
<div class="row" style="position: relative;">

  <div class="slider responsive single-item" style="margin-bottom: 0;">
     <div><img src="http://placehold.it/1920x455"/></div>
     <div><img src="http://placehold.it/1920x455"/></div>
     <div><img src="http://placehold.it/1920x455"/></div>
     <div><img src="http://placehold.it/1920x455"/></div>
  </div>

</div>
</section>
```

And I am also using foundation zurb which is why theres a row class. Here is my javascript to control my slider:

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
      $('.single-item').slick({
        autoplay: true,
        arrows: false,
        pauseOnHover: false,
        draggable: false,
        mobileFirst: true
      });
    });
```

Any and all answers are appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: It would be much easier to debug if you reproduce your issue in a fiddle. http://jsfiddle.net

Comment: Which browser are you using? Just tried to [reproduce](http://jsfiddle.net/m06x0x8b/), no issues tho.

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
      $('.single-item').slick({
        autoplay: true,
        arrows: false,
        pauseOnHover: false,
        draggable: false,
        mobileFirst: true
      });
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the `infinite: false` property to slider when you initialize it.

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
    $('.single-item').slick({
        autoplay: true,
        arrows: false,
        pauseOnHover: false,
        draggable: false,
        mobileFirst: true,
        infinite: false
    });
 });
```